# Guest User cannot edit ContentDocument

Tags: files, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

We have a system in place to allow guest users (under some circumstances) to modify files in Salesforce (those pesky `ContentDocument` and `ContentVersion` records).
This system works in the development sandbox.

However, after deploying to the integration sandbox we seem to have lost that capability.
`Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 069XXXXXXXXXXXX; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY`
I have determined that the guest user can retrieve the `ContentDocument` in question, but cannot edit it (modify the `Description` field or add a new `ContentDocumentLink` record).

All of the code has correctly been copied (via `git` and `SFDX`).
To the best of my knowledge, all configurations have also been correctly duplicated (profiles, permission sets, Site access...)

What is the <s>obvious</s> obscure thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the obvious obscure thing that I'm missing?

I was missing `Allow site guest users to upload files`

Setup > General Settings > Allow site guest users to upload files

Let this be a lesson to <s>you</s> me: always document everything, *especially* the configuration steps.